# Facet size using tire gem for elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I am a newbie to elasticsearch. I was trying to create facets using tire gem for my web application. But I was only able to create 7 entries to any facet. Is there a way that I can manipulate the size of facet in tire gem for elasticsearch?

query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "rank": {
              "lte": 50
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "rank": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "facets": {
    "univ": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state_id",
        "size": 50,
        "all_terms": false
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a size to the facet:

```
facet 'countries' do
    terms : countries, size: 15
    facet_filter :and, search_filter  unless search_filter.empty?
end
```

Comment: I tried the above method. However, when I include a new facet it doesn't show up in the facet list. Any idea where Im going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a mapping for it? The field you want as facet should be indexed.